# Web query throws error: import currenturl matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running the following code.

```
Sub HREF_Web()

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim output As Object

Range("A1:C10000").Clear

' delete all queries
Dim pq As Object
For Each pq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
    pq.Delete
Next

' delete all connections
Dim cn As Object
For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    cn.Delete
Next


Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L1") ' getting url from the worksheet

Do
'DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.document
Set output = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")


For Each link In output
    Debug.Print link.innerHTML
    If link.innerHTML Like "*" & "Data Corrections" & "*" Then
        link.Click

        currenturl = ie.LocationURL

            ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(currenturl))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data0, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Data Notice Page"", type any}, {""eMBS Inc"", type any}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "   " & _
            " #""Changed Type"""
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0"";Extended Properties=""""" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0]")
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0"
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("A2").Select

    End If

Next

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

The 'currenturl' variable is coming from the newly opened IE window.  Maybe that's not the way to do this kind of thing, but I thought it was going to work.  Basically, I want to loop through all HREF tags in a parent, look for tags that contain 'Data Corrections', click these links, navigate to these children URLs (there are 4), and import the data from the 'Table 0' object.

Here is an image of the error.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this can't be done with XMLHTTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error message you are receiving is from Power Query.

Your variable `currenturl` is defined in VBA but not in Power Query (the two are separate and Power Query does not have knowledge of your VBA variables or what they may contain).

So when your `M` code is evaluated, it knows you want you want to pass some `Expression` called `currenturl` as an argument to the `Web.Contents` function but it can't find `currenturl` being defined/assigned anywhere (within its own evaluation chain).

I think your options are:

- Instead of `"...Web.Contents(currenturl)..."`, try `"...Web.Contents(""" & currenturl & """)..."` (i.e. let VBA evaluate `currenturl` and pass its actual value to Power Query, rather than handing Power Query an expression that originates from outside of its evaluation chain/scope). This might be the quickest fix, although the URL needs to be surrounded by `"` on each side, so that Power Query evaluates it as text/string -- and there may be other things to watch out for as well.
- Use a more pure approach i.e. either all in VBA, or all in `M`/Power Query (probably more work for you, but it means you don't need to have VBA talk to Power Query, or vice versa).
- Have your VBA code dump all `currenturl`s (from all loop iterations) to a specific range/column, then have Power Query look at that particular range, return an `M` table for each `currenturl`, then combine and load as one table to an Excel sheet. Technically, once you've made the query, you'd only need to refresh it (can be done from VBA), but making the query will require knowledge of `M` or Power Query GUI.

Comment: Thanks chillin.  I knew it was something like that.  I just didn't know it was exactly that issue.